# Setting alarm ringtone on Google clock on Marshmallow

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, samsung-galaxy-s7

Earlier (actually ... I do not know when that stopped working) when I would try to change the ringtone of my alarm from the Google clock app, I would get to choose which "source" I would get the tone from, there was a default list, and I could also choose a file from my own library.

Now I can only use the said default list. I have a tone that I had set by the described method in the list but I have no way to *add* anything to that list.

Are there solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Install [ES Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop)

Play the tone using ES and follow steps to  set it as ringtone, notification or alarm. Selected track would be added to default options panel of ringtone/ alarm

[image]
[image]

**Note:** ES Explorer has privacy and security concerns, so if you are not aware of how to sandbox it and use it, uninstall immediately after this operation of setting ringtones

Comment: By sandboxing , I mean block it's internet access using firewalls or other apps