# Can't set ringtone / notification sound from internal storage

Tags: ringtone, nexus-5x, 7.1-nougat

After a factory reset (internal storage was not wiped) on my Nexus 5X running stock Android 7.1.2, I'm no longer able to choose a ringtone, notification sound or alarm sound from internal storage. If I choose to pick a file with Solid Explorer instead of Media Storage, it sets the ringtone to None. I've tried clearing app data for Media Storage as well as wiping ART/Dalvik cache.

EDIT: I forgot to mention Tasker cannot play media files in internal storage, either.

```
bullhead:/ # ls -l /storage/emulated
drwxrwx--x 66 root sdcard_rw 4096 2017-07-08 09:13 0

bullhead:/ # ls -l /storage/emulated/0
drwxrwx--x  2 root sdcard_rw    4096 2017-01-30 15:56 Alarms
drwxrwx--x  2 root sdcard_rw    4096 2017-02-24 18:45 Notifications
drwxrwx--x  2 root sdcard_rw    4096 2017-01-30 16:09 Ringtones
```

If I look at the folder permissions for /data/media/0 in Solid Explorer, the Owner & Group are unknown.

I'm thinking of backing up everything in internal storage, wiping it and testing again before restoring the backup. Is there anything else I could try before spending hours copying multiple gigabytes back & forth?

Comment: You can try with the app [mentioned here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/168752/131553) - though that question is in a different context  / OS

Comment: Using that method with ES File Explorer works, but I'd have to play and set each and every sound file I have to get them to appear in the Media Storage menu. This is a cumbersome workaround, not a solution. I appreciate the reply, nonetheless.